# Can a spell that does thunder damage be amplified by thaumaturgy?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can a spell that does thunder damage be amplified by *thaumaturgy*? As in deal more damage, or be effected by it in anyway?

Comment: Is there a reason you think Thaumaturgy *would* affect thunder damage?

Comment: You could try asking the ramifications of allowing Thaumaturgy to increase thunder damage.

Comment: Okay, even though I'm not the asker, I would like to understand the heavy downvoting. Thunder damage is usually associated with sound, and Thaumaturgy can increase your sound volume, so it's not **that** bad of a question, imo, folks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

Thaumaturgy only creates harmless effects.

Thaumaturgy does the following:

> You create one of the following magical effects within range:
>
> - Your voice booms up to three times as loud as ***normal*** for 1 minute.
> - You cause flames to flicker, brighten, dim, or change color for 1 minute.
> - You cause harmless tremors in the ground for 1 minute.
> - You create a sound that originates from a point of your choice within range.
> - You cause an unlocked door or window to fly open or slam shut.
> - You alter the appearance of your eyes for 1 minute.
>
> If you cast this spell multiple times, you can have up to three of its 1-minute effects active at a time, and you can dismiss such an effect as an action.

Emphasis mine.

Even if you have a skill that lets you scream so hard you deal thunder damage the basis for thaumaturgy is your "normal" volume. Weapons or other tools that deal thunder damage are not affected by the spell.

Comment: Now, the question is if your *normal* voice causes thunder damage...

Comment: @SeraphsWrath Only if you are as good singing as me in the shower.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Spells do only what they say and don't do what they don't say. Thaumaturgy says nothing about increasing thunder damage, so it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

## No

The only part of *[thaumaturgy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thaumaturgy)* that might imply this is (from PHB, pg. 282)

> Your voice booms up to three times as loud as normal for 1 minute.

which is where I assume your question comes from.

This does not allow boosting damage of any kind. If it did, it would say so.

Answer (score 4):

## No

The only effects of *thaumaturgy* even close to possibly relevant to amplifying sound are:

> - Your voice booms up to three times as loud as normal for 1 minute [...]
> - You create an instantaneous sound that originates from a point of your  choice within range, such as a rumble of thunder, the cry of a
>   raven, or ominous whisper.

However, none of these would do anything to thunder damage from another spell. The first involves amplifying your own voice only and the second involves the creation of a harmless sound.

Spells do only what they say they do and increasing the damage of thunder effects is not listed at all. In fact, none of the effects of *thaumaturgy* do or enhance damage in any way. So this idea is really not feasible on any level.